# git word-diff-regex that works with multiline changes?

Tags: git

Consider a simple file like this:

*Commited:*

```
foo;
```

*Edited:*

```
bar;
```

Now, when I run `git diff --word-diff-regex="[a-z]+"`, it gives me

```
[-foo-]{+bar+};
```

So, it shows that the word `foo` has been replaced by `bar`. Note that the **semicolon is not marked as changed**. That's fine.

---

Now, if I add another line to the file like this:

```
bar;

qux;
```

the above does not work anymore:

```
$ git diff --word-diff-regex="[a-z]+"
```

*Expected output:*

```
[-foo-]{+bar+};

{+qux;+}
```

*Actual output:*

```
[-foo-]{+bar;+}

{+qux+};
```

Note that the **semicolon in the first line is now considered part of a word**.
 The [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_options) state

> Anything between these matches is considered whitespace and ignored(!) for the purposes of finding differences.

Then why does it not ignore the semicolons? Is that a bug? Can I use a better regex to make it work?

<sub>*I actually use a more sophisticated regex in reality, but the problem is the same.*</sub>

---

#### Edit

Strangely, it works when the committed file contains an additional newline like so:

```
foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

might be relevant to those who end up in this post like me.

Since I use markdown for my documents not related to programming, and also using git to track the changes, others like me might end up here where changes for a date like "2022-09-12" into "2022-09-13" is relevant to be noticed.

And so, I found this solution (finally after spending inordinate hours tinkering) from the documentation of git itself

```
git diff [commit hash] --word-diff-regex=. -U1000 -- [file name]
```

`-U1000` is a hardcoded solution for now, it's a bit irksome, but it'll do for now. In my context, it shows the whole file (having only around 500 lines in the file)

and the `--word-diff-regex=.` is something I got from the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-options#Documentation/diff-options.txt---word-diff-regexltregexgt)

I used to use `--word-diff-regex='(\w+|\s|\.|,|\d+)'` to capture periods '.', commas ',', spaces, and words but changed it into the one found in the docs because the following change wasn't highlighted

from

```
... # some other text
<h6>version 1</h6>
<h6>2022-09-20</h6>
... # some other text
```

into

```
... # some other text
<h6>version 1.1</h6>
<h6>2022-09-23</h6>
... # some other text
```

running git in powershell:

```
PS C:...> git diff fbf86a6cfa240cb0a0e98fe8ebf80171d2b801fb --word-diff-regex='(\w+|\s|\.|,|\d+)' -- file.md
diff --git a/file.md b/file.md
index 6c0ce48..0d3b482 100644
--- a/file.md
+++ b/file.md
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
...
<h6>version 1{+.1+}</h6>
<h6>2022-09-23</h6>
```

But with only `.` as a regex pattern

```
PS C:...> git diff fbf86a6cfa240cb0a0e98fe8ebf80171d2b801fb --word-diff-regex=. -- file.md
diff --git a/file.md b/file.md
index 6c0ce48..0d3b482 100644
--- a/file.md
+++ b/file.md
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
...
<h6>version 1{+.1+}</h6>
<h6>2022-09-2[-0-]{+3+}</h6>
```

The change in date is now highlighted.

Hope this helps someone.

Edited:
I added the pattern `\d+`, because it is actually included in my usual regex pattern for seeking changes, but even with it added, the change from "20" to "23" still wasn't detected.