# git: List files that changed between two commits, but exclude whitespace changes and break changes

Tags: java, git, git-diff

I want to retrieve a list of all the files that *really* changed between two commits. So, I want to ignore files where the only things that changed are part of the following list:

- empty line added / removed
- line containing just an `*` (and possibly whitespace) added / removed
- indentation changed or whitespace added after lines
- breaks inserted into any line, e.g.:

Before:

```
System.out.println("bar" + "foo");
```

After:

```
System.out.println("bar" + 
    "foo");
```

These kinds of changes should be ignored. I know that this may be a very complicated task, but I don't think I'm the first person needing this kind of thing.

### Update

After some help in the comments I came up with

```
git diff --word-diff-regex='^\*|[^[:space:]]' --ignore-space-at-eol --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-space-change --ignore-all-space hash1..hash2 --name-only
```

But I am not quite sure if that actually does everything I want. Can someone verify that?

Comment: `git diff -w` ? (won't handle the `*` though)

Comment: This does provide the condition of the first bulletpoint, but not any of the other three.

Comment: what do you have tried ? you should give a look first on https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: My best try is `git diff --name-only --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-space-change --ignore-space-at-eol hash1 hash2`

Comment: You could try with the `--word-diff-regex=<regex>` option. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140915/git-word-diff-regex-that-works-with-multiline-changes

Comment: `git diff --name-only --word-diff-regex='^\*|[^[:space:]]' --ignore-space-at-eol --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-space-change --ignore-all-space
hash1..hash2` is actually quite good. I'm not quite sure if it really ignores everything I want, though.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer that i come up with, but it´s not so good it´s to make a local branch of the previous commit format them the same way as the new, and compare in the normal way the branch and the head version.